# How to make a character navigate a 2d grid of text java

Tags: java, text, 2d

(I am posting this because I could not find any examples online and wanted to share.)

How can I show a basic x,y 2d coordinate system used to navigate a character (displayed O) through a grid of Xs?

I don't want to use Java GUI (Swing) but command line instead.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Adventure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            boolean gameActive = true;// keeps track of if game is active when program needs to stop
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x = 0;// initial placement, doesn't matter
            int y = 0;// initial placement, doesn't matter
            while (gameActive) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {// prints columns
                            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {//prints rows
                                    if (i == y & j == x) {//checks if the coordinate is taken up
                                            System.out.print("O");
                                    } else {
                                            System.out.print("X");
                                    }
                            }
                            System.out.println("");

                    }

                    System.out.println("Enter 1 to quit");
                    String move = in.next();
                    if (move.equals("1")) { //quits 
                            gameActive = false;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("u")) { //movement commands
                            y--;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("d")) {
                            y++;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("l")) {
                            x--;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("r")) {
                            x++;
                    }

            }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @toKrause he is trying to help others by posting this. Also, Joshua, you should write the code as the answer and explain a bit. You can do this by checking the "answer my own question" at the bottom of the page after you click "edit".

Comment: This doesn't seem to be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at all.

Comment: As it stands, this is off topic (@toKrause) - if you would like to share, you can ask it as a question, eg "How do I navigate a character in a 2d grid system" as the title, then pad out the question so that anyone else with a similar problem can find it, then provide this code as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Strickland did it this way: (I take no credit from this whatsoever!!)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Adventure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            boolean gameActive = true;// keeps track of if game is active when program needs to stop
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x = 0;// initial placement, doesn't matter
            int y = 0;// initial placement, doesn't matter
            while (gameActive) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {// prints columns
                            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {//prints rows
                                    if (i == y & j == x) {//checks if the coordinate is taken up
                                            System.out.print("O");
                                    } else {
                                            System.out.print("X");
                                    }
                            }
                            System.out.println("");

                    }

                    System.out.println("Enter 1 to quit");
                    String move = in.next();
                    if (move.equals("1")) { //quits 
                            gameActive = false;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("u")) { //movement commands
                            y--;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("d")) {
                            y++;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("l")) {
                            x--;
                    }
                    if (move.equals("r")) {
                            x++;
                    }

            }

    }

}
```